# Google recaptcha 2 doesn't load on clicking link

Tags: captcha, recaptcha

I have implemented google recaptcha 2 in footer and welcome pop up. When I browse home page, the captcha loads but when I click any link, the catpcha disappears from footer. This happens in all clicks through out whole site. 
Here is snippets I have implemented:

This code goes under head tag:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=myCallBack&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

HTML Part:

```
 <div class="field" id="google_recaptcha_container1">
     <div id="g-recaptcha1" class="g-recaptcha1" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey ?>" >
</div>
</div>
```

" >

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myCallBack = function () {
        //Render the recaptcha2 on the element with ID "recaptcha2"
        var recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha1', {
            'sitekey': '<?php echo $siteKey; ?>', //Replace this with your Site key
            'theme': 'light'
        });

        var recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha2', {
            'sitekey': '<?php echo $siteKey; ?>', //Replace this with your Site key
            'theme': 'light'
        });
    };
```

Note: This works fine for the first time when page loads but it doesn't if you refresh by clicking refresh button or click any link.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.